# Proper way to avoid duplicating test data for unit tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, tdd, moq

Lets say that I have the following Unit Test for Entity Framework 6 using Moq:

```
    public void Save_Employee_via_context()
    {
        var MockContext = new Mock<DcmDataContext>();

        var MockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Employee>>();

        MockContext.Setup(m => m.Employees).Returns(MockSet.Object);

        var service = new GeneralService(MockContext.Object);

        //Test valid inputs

        for (int i = 0; i < TestData.ValidEmployees.Count; i++)
        {
            service.AddEmployee(TestData.ValidEmployees[i]);
            //veryfy that it was properly inserted
            Assert.AreEqual(TestData.ValidEmployees[i],MockSet.Object.Find(TestData.ValidEmployees[i].EmployeeID));
        }
        //Ensure that the proper methods were called each time.  It is implied that this happened if the above 
        //Assert methods passed, but double checking never killed anybody
        MockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Employee>()), Times.Exactly(TestData.ValidEmployees.Count));
        MockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Exactly(TestData.ValidEmployees.Count));

        //Test invalid Inputs

        MockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Employee>>();
        //InvalidEmployees is a Dictionary<Employee,Type>, where Type is the type of exeption that should eb thrown if 
        //You attempt to add that Employee
        foreach (var pair in TestData.InvalidEmployees)
        {
            try
            {
                service.AddEmployee(pair.Key);
                //AddEmployee *SHOULD* throw an exception here here.. if not...
                Assert.Fail();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Was it the exception that I was expecting to catch?
                Assert.Equals(ex.GetType(), pair.Value);
            }
        }
        //ensure that nothing new has been added (redundant, I know, but it doesn't hurt)
        MockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Employee>()), Times.Never);
        MockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Exactly(TestData.ValidEmployees.Count));

    }
```

`TestData` is a Static Class that I have that holds lists for each model type that I want to test, along with several test cases for each, with both valid and invalid inputs.

I created my test like this because my objects can be fairly large (`Employee`, for example, has around 15 properties), and as such there is a wide array of test cases that I want to run in order for each test to be thorough.  I didn't want to copy/paste, each array of test sample data every single method that needs it, so I wanted to store it in a static container.

I feel like this poses a problem, however.  For instance, one of the properties of `Employee` is `Position`.  You know, what job they have.  it is a required property, and an exception should be thrown if that position is either null, or doesn't already exist in the database.  That means that in order for the above test to be valid, I'm going to need some mock positions to be in there as well.  Oh, but each Position has a `Department` Attribute... so that needs to be set up too...

Do you see where I am going with this?  How can I properly test my code without a full suite of test data to test it against?  Well then, I suppose I'll have to write a full suite of test data.  Which I did.

The problem is, where do I put it?  I decided to put in all in the TestData Class.
This, however, presents a set of problems.  Initialization is the biggest one, because I feel like I have to neuter my test data in order to make initialization even remotely feasible.  For instance, all of my navigation properties are probably going to have to be `null`.  How could I have my `ValidEmployees` each have a `List<Clients>`, and each `Client` have an assigned `Employee` without, once again, hard duplicating each Employee as a property of `Client`, and in the `List<Employee>` that each `Position` is going to have.  wouldn't it be nice to have `Clients = {ValidClients[0],ValidClients[1]` within `ValidEmployees` and `SalesRepresentative =  ValidEmployees[0]` within  ValidClients?

I also feel like I need that Navigation data.  will

```
 Assert.AreEqual
 (
     TestData.ValidEmployees[i],
     MockSet.Object.Find(TestData.ValidEmployees[i].EmployeeID
 )
```

still  return true if ValidEmployees doesn't have navigationData in it? Does this mean I should find another way of ensuring state?

Anyway, these are the problems that I am running into.  Am I just setting up my Unit tests completely wrong?  How else am I supposed to get robust, independent, DRY and accurate unit tests?  What am I missing here?

Any help is appreciated, even if it means starting from scratch with a different mindset.  This is my first project where I am taking testing very seriously, but I feel like it isn't going so well.  As such, sorry for the wall of text.  Sometimes I feel like i'm not asking the right question to get where I want to go.

Comment: Just skimming over your test method, it's breaking a fundamental rule of unit testing in that each test should only attempt to test one thing (hence the name Unit test). As a start I'd break that method down into a series of unit tests each testing discreet pieces of functionality. You've got a lot of questions in this post but as a start I'd suggest having a read of Mark Seeman's blog on the AAA pattern in Unit Tests http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/06/24/a-heuristic-for-formatting-code-according-to-the-aaa-pattern/

Comment: @Damon I've actually seen that blog before, and I totally get it.  Really I do, but am I just alone in a world where I have objects that are so interdependent, that having a simple Arrange of `new BasketItem("Chocolate", 50, 3),`  almost feels like it is mocking me (no pun intended).  Should I just be doomed to have Arrange statements that are 40 lines long in each of my unit 500 unit tests? It is numbers like that that almost make me want to just forget testing and take my lumps later if need be.  Why can't I find anything with even a moderate level of complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your tests, it appears that your service.AddEmployee does too much :). You can split the validation logic, etc.

Consider test like this (to lead your design). This uses a [FakeDbSet](http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/):

```
[Test]
public void Should_add_any_valid_employees_and_save_them()
{
   //arrange
   var validator = new Mock<IEmployeeValidator>();
   validator.Setup(v => v.Validate(It.IsAny<Employee>())).Returns(true);

   // ... setup the context and the dbset

   var service = new MyService(validator.Object, mockContext.Object)

   var newData = new List<EmployeeDto>
      {
         new EmployeeDto{Id = 1},
         new EmployeeDto{Id = 2}
      }

   // act
   service.AddEmployees(newData);

   // assert
   mockContext.Verify(c => c.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
   Assert.True(fakeDbSet.Count == newData.Count);
   CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent( newData.Select(e=>e.Id), mockData.Select(e=>e.Id));
}

[Test]
public void Should_not_add_any_invalid_employees()
{
   //arrange
   var validator = new Mock<IEmployeeValidator>();
   validator.Setup(v => v.Validate(It.IsAny<Employee>())).Returns(false);

   // ... setup the context and the dbset

   var service = new MyService(validator.Object, mockContext.Object)

   var newData = new List<EmployeeDto>
      {
         new EmployeeDto{Id = 1},
         new EmployeeDto{Id = 2}
      }

   // act
   service.AddEmployees(newData);

   // assert
   mockContext.Verify(c => c.SaveChanges(), Times.Never());
   Assert.True(fakeDbSet.Count == 0);
   CollectionAssert.IsEmpty( mockData );
}
```

You can throw in the mix IEmployeeDtoToEmployee mapper as well, so you abstract this part of the functionality as well.

Comment: I'm assuming that after these two tests might come a test that actually tests whether the Validator works or not?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second part of the question (about test data). I would not use a test data class for my tests, this will make the tests fragile and may introduce subtle bugs as a change to the test data class may affect numerous unrelated tests in different test classes, google Object Mother Anti-Pattern.

I went down the Object Mother route before and ended up with a whole project containing all my test data. When I needed a new variation of the test data, I kept altering/adding to the object mother. Needless to say, the project became bloated and unmaintainable very quickly. Also, the fact that some unit tests started failing because of these changes (as there is a dependency on this shared data), and the extra time spent to fix them, made it a real annoyance. Hence, I decided that a better approach is to let unit test classes own the data they use (in other words, the test data is contained within the Test Fixture). To achieve this, I introduced a test data builder project but this meant that I have another project to maintain and change (when needed) whenever I write a unit test. Honestly, I'd rather concentrate on the unit tests themselves and not worry about the plumbing and that's why I started using a test data generator. I'm using [NBuilder](https://github.com/garethdown44/nbuilder/) but I've heard very good things about [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) as well. These will allow you to build your test data, concentrate on the parts that are relevant to the behaviour you're testing and let the builder generate random data for the ones that are not (you can control/override the random generators). I'm of the opinion that in order to improve the unit test readability, you should only show (or emphasise) the data that affects the behaviour that you're testing rather than bloat your unit test with irrelevant information.

Example:

```
var validEmployees = Builder<Employees>.CreateListOfSize(10)
                                       .All()
                                       .With(x => x.IsActive = true)
                                       .And(x => x.LeaveDate = null)
                                       .Build();
```

Comment: This looks amazing, thanks for sharing how you overcame that problem.  I feel the same way!